# Showing name of admin on message from database

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Maybe is kind of simple but currently I show last message and message from like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>User</th>
       <th style="width: 100px">Last from</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach($messages as $message)
      <tr @if(!$message->from_admin && !$message->read_state) class="info" @endif>
           <td>{{ $message->message_id }}</td>
           <td>{{ $message->user->username }}</td>
           <td>{{ $message->from_admin ? 'Admin' : '<span class="name-highlight">User</span>' }}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make `Admin` variable from database. So in my controller I have this so far

```
public function messages() {
    $query = Message::
        whereRaw('messages.message_id = (select max(message_id) from `messages` m2 where m2.user_id = messages.user_id)')
        ->orderBy('message_id', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return View::make('site.admin.messages', [
        'messages' => $query
    ]);
}
```

In message Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In admin table I have column called `is_admin` which is `1` for admin and `0` for all other users.

What I'm trying to display is `Admin` name from database here

```
<td>{{ $message->from_admin ? 'Admin' : '<span class="name-highlight">User</span>' }}</td>
```

Can anyone help how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a relation who sent the message and who received it with the *users* table? This way if it's admin you could get the name from this relation.

Comment: I have column `is_admin` in `users` table which is `1` when user is admin and column `from_admin` which is also `1` in messages table when admin wrote it.

Comment: You have to have a relation which user sent this message to be able to get the admin name. In your messages table you have to store the user ID of the user who sent the message.

Comment: I have `user_id` column in `messages` table but it is storing only the id of the user which is sent message to admin. That's why there is `from_admin` column..

Comment: I've added image of database how it's look like when user write to admin.